# Is my hard drive dying?

Tags: hard-drive, debian, sata

Im gettings strange error messages in the terminal.

This is the output of dmesg:

```
[ 3317.715990] ata4.00: exception Emask 0x10 SAct 0x78 SErr 0x400000 action 0x6 frozen
[ 3317.716113] ata4.00: irq_stat 0x08000000, interface fatal error
[ 3317.716199] ata4: SError: { Handshk }
[ 3317.716262] ata4.00: failed command: WRITE FPDMA QUEUED
[ 3317.716341] ata4.00: cmd 61/00:18:3f:14:13/04:00:00:00:00/40 tag 3 ncq 524288 out
[ 3317.716342]          res 40/00:34:17:05:13/00:00:00:00:00/40 Emask 0x10 (ATA bus error)
[ 3317.716502] ata4.00: status: { DRDY }
[ 3317.716563] ata4.00: failed command: WRITE FPDMA QUEUED
[ 3317.716634] ata4.00: cmd 61/00:20:3f:18:13/04:00:00:00:00/40 tag 4 ncq 524288 out
[ 3317.716635]          res 40/00:34:17:05:13/00:00:00:00:00/40 Emask 0x10 (ATA bus error)
[ 3317.716795] ata4.00: status: { DRDY }
[ 3317.716856] ata4.00: failed command: WRITE FPDMA QUEUED
[ 3317.716926] ata4.00: cmd 61/80:28:3f:1c:13/01:00:00:00:00/40 tag 5 ncq 196608 out
[ 3317.716927]          res 40/00:34:17:05:13/00:00:00:00:00/40 Emask 0x10 (ATA bus error)
[ 3317.717087] ata4.00: status: { DRDY }
[ 3317.717185] ata4.00: failed command: WRITE FPDMA QUEUED
[ 3317.717293] ata4.00: cmd 61/28:30:17:05:13/01:00:00:00:00/40 tag 6 ncq 151552 out
[ 3317.717293]          res 40/00:34:17:05:13/00:00:00:00:00/40 Emask 0x10 (ATA bus error)
[ 3317.717606] ata4.00: status: { DRDY }
[ 3317.717705] ata4: hard resetting link
[ 3318.208111] ata4: SATA link up 6.0 Gbps (SStatus 133 SControl 300)
[ 3318.211624] ata4.00: configured for UDMA/133
[ 3318.211637] ata4: EH complete
[ 4120.100879] ata4.00: exception Emask 0x10 SAct 0x7fffff07 SErr 0x400000 action 0x6 frozen
[ 4120.101038] ata4.00: irq_stat 0x08000000, interface fatal error
[ 4120.101147] ata4: SError: { Handshk }
[ 4120.101246] ata4.00: failed command: WRITE FPDMA QUEUED
[ 4120.101353] ata4.00: cmd 61/00:00:3f:b0:2d/04:00:00:00:00/40 tag 0 ncq 524288 out
[ 4120.101354]          res 40/00:f4:3f:0c:2e/00:00:00:00:00/40 Emask 0x10 (ATA bus error)
[ 4120.101657] ata4.00: status: { DRDY }
[ 4120.101755] ata4.00: failed command: WRITE FPDMA QUEUED
[ 4120.101862] ata4.00: cmd 61/00:08:3f:b4:2d/04:00:00:00:00/40 tag 1 ncq 524288 out
[ 4120.101863]          res 40/00:f4:3f:0c:2e/00:00:00:00:00/40 Emask 0x10 (ATA bus error)
[ 4120.102169] ata4.00: status: { DRDY }
[ 4120.102267] ata4.00: failed command: WRITE FPDMA QUEUED
[ 4120.102373] ata4.00: cmd 61/00:10:3f:b8:2d/04:00:00:00:00/40 tag 2 ncq 524288 out
[ 4120.102374]          res 40/00:f4:3f:0c:2e/00:00:00:00:00/40 Emask 0x10 (ATA bus error)
[ 4120.102677] ata4.00: status: { DRDY }
[ 4120.102775] ata4.00: failed command: WRITE FPDMA QUEUED
[ 4120.102882] ata4.00: cmd 61/00:40:3f:a8:2d/04:00:00:00:00/40 tag 8 ncq 524288 out
[ 4120.102882]          res 40/00:f4:3f:0c:2e/00:00:00:00:00/40 Emask 0x10 (ATA bus error)
[ 4120.103186] ata4.00: status: { DRDY }
[ 4120.103284] ata4.00: failed command: WRITE FPDMA QUEUED
[ 4120.103390] ata4.00: cmd 61/00:48:3f:ac:2d/04:00:00:00:00/40 tag 9 ncq 524288 out
[ 4120.103391]          res 40/00:f4:3f:0c:2e/00:00:00:00:00/40 Emask 0x10 (ATA bus error)
[ 4120.103695] ata4.00: status: { DRDY }
[ 4120.103792] ata4.00: failed command: WRITE FPDMA QUEUED
[ 4120.103899] ata4.00: cmd 61/00:50:3f:bc:2d/04:00:00:00:00/40 tag 10 ncq 524288 out
[ 4120.103900]          res 40/00:f4:3f:0c:2e/00:00:00:00:00/40 Emask 0x10 (ATA bus error)
[ 4120.104216] ata4.00: status: { DRDY }
[ 4120.104315] ata4.00: failed command: WRITE FPDMA QUEUED
[ 4120.104424] ata4.00: cmd 61/00:58:3f:c0:2d/04:00:00:00:00/40 tag 11 ncq 524288 out
[ 4120.104425]          res 40/00:f4:3f:0c:2e/00:00:00:00:00/40 Emask 0x10 (ATA bus error)
[ 4120.104730] ata4.00: status: { DRDY }
[ 4120.104829] ata4.00: failed command: WRITE FPDMA QUEUED
[ 4120.104937] ata4.00: cmd 61/00:60:3f:c4:2d/04:00:00:00:00/40 tag 12 ncq 524288 out
[ 4120.104938]          res 40/00:f4:3f:0c:2e/00:00:00:00:00/40 Emask 0x10 (ATA bus error)
[ 4120.105243] ata4.00: status: { DRDY }
[ 4120.105342] ata4.00: failed command: WRITE FPDMA QUEUED
[ 4120.105450] ata4.00: cmd 61/00:68:3f:c8:2d/04:00:00:00:00/40 tag 13 ncq 524288 out
[ 4120.105451]          res 40/00:f4:3f:0c:2e/00:00:00:00:00/40 Emask 0x10 (ATA bus error)
[ 4120.105756] ata4.00: status: { DRDY }
[ 4120.105855] ata4.00: failed command: WRITE FPDMA QUEUED
[ 4120.105963] ata4.00: cmd 61/00:70:3f:cc:2d/04:00:00:00:00/40 tag 14 ncq 524288 out
[ 4120.105964]          res 40/00:f4:3f:0c:2e/00:00:00:00:00/40 Emask 0x10 (ATA bus error)
[ 4120.106269] ata4.00: status: { DRDY }
[ 4120.106368] ata4.00: failed command: WRITE FPDMA QUEUED
[ 4120.106476] ata4.00: cmd 61/00:78:3f:d0:2d/04:00:00:00:00/40 tag 15 ncq 524288 out
[ 4120.106477]          res 40/00:f4:3f:0c:2e/00:00:00:00:00/40 Emask 0x10 (ATA bus error)
[ 4120.106782] ata4.00: status: { DRDY }
[ 4120.106881] ata4.00: failed command: WRITE FPDMA QUEUED
[ 4120.106990] ata4.00: cmd 61/00:80:3f:d4:2d/04:00:00:00:00/40 tag 16 ncq 524288 out
[ 4120.106990]          res 40/00:f4:3f:0c:2e/00:00:00:00:00/40 Emask 0x10 (ATA bus error)
[ 4120.107295] ata4.00: status: { DRDY }
[ 4120.107394] ata4.00: failed command: WRITE FPDMA QUEUED
[ 4120.107502] ata4.00: cmd 61/00:88:3f:d8:2d/04:00:00:00:00/40 tag 17 ncq 524288 out
[ 4120.107503]          res 40/00:f4:3f:0c:2e/00:00:00:00:00/40 Emask 0x10 (ATA bus error)
[ 4120.107808] ata4.00: status: { DRDY }
[ 4120.107907] ata4.00: failed command: WRITE FPDMA QUEUED
[ 4120.108024] ata4.00: cmd 61/00:90:3f:dc:2d/04:00:00:00:00/40 tag 18 ncq 524288 out
[ 4120.108025]          res 40/00:f4:3f:0c:2e/00:00:00:00:00/40 Emask 0x10 (ATA bus error)
[ 4120.108332] ata4.00: status: { DRDY }
[ 4120.108433] ata4.00: failed command: WRITE FPDMA QUEUED
[ 4120.108542] ata4.00: cmd 61/00:98:3f:e0:2d/04:00:00:00:00/40 tag 19 ncq 524288 out
[ 4120.108543]          res 40/00:f4:3f:0c:2e/00:00:00:00:00/40 Emask 0x10 (ATA bus error)
[ 4120.108848] ata4.00: status: { DRDY }
[ 4120.108949] ata4.00: failed command: WRITE FPDMA QUEUED
[ 4120.109058] ata4.00: cmd 61/00:a0:3f:e4:2d/04:00:00:00:00/40 tag 20 ncq 524288 out
[ 4120.109059]          res 40/00:f4:3f:0c:2e/00:00:00:00:00/40 Emask 0x10 (ATA bus error)
[ 4120.109365] ata4.00: status: { DRDY }
[ 4120.109463] ata4.00: failed command: WRITE FPDMA QUEUED
[ 4120.109573] ata4.00: cmd 61/00:a8:3f:e8:2d/04:00:00:00:00/40 tag 21 ncq 524288 out
[ 4120.109574]          res 40/00:f4:3f:0c:2e/00:00:00:00:00/40 Emask 0x10 (ATA bus error)
[ 4120.109881] ata4.00: status: { DRDY }
[ 4120.109981] ata4.00: failed command: WRITE FPDMA QUEUED
[ 4120.110090] ata4.00: cmd 61/00:b0:3f:ec:2d/04:00:00:00:00/40 tag 22 ncq 524288 out
[ 4120.110091]          res 40/00:f4:3f:0c:2e/00:00:00:00:00/40 Emask 0x10 (ATA bus error)
[ 4120.110396] ata4.00: status: { DRDY }
[ 4120.110496] ata4.00: failed command: WRITE FPDMA QUEUED
[ 4120.110604] ata4.00: cmd 61/00:b8:3f:f0:2d/04:00:00:00:00/40 tag 23 ncq 524288 out
[ 4120.110606]          res 40/00:f4:3f:0c:2e/00:00:00:00:00/40 Emask 0x10 (ATA bus error)
[ 4120.110911] ata4.00: status: { DRDY }
[ 4120.111010] ata4.00: failed command: WRITE FPDMA QUEUED
[ 4120.111118] ata4.00: cmd 61/00:c0:3f:f4:2d/04:00:00:00:00/40 tag 24 ncq 524288 out
[ 4120.111119]          res 40/00:f4:3f:0c:2e/00:00:00:00:00/40 Emask 0x10 (ATA bus error)
[ 4120.111425] ata4.00: status: { DRDY }
[ 4120.111523] ata4.00: failed command: WRITE FPDMA QUEUED
[ 4120.111632] ata4.00: cmd 61/00:c8:3f:f8:2d/04:00:00:00:00/40 tag 25 ncq 524288 out
[ 4120.111633]          res 40/00:f4:3f:0c:2e/00:00:00:00:00/40 Emask 0x10 (ATA bus error)
[ 4120.111938] ata4.00: status: { DRDY }
[ 4120.112052] ata4.00: failed command: WRITE FPDMA QUEUED
[ 4120.112162] ata4.00: cmd 61/00:d0:3f:fc:2d/04:00:00:00:00/40 tag 26 ncq 524288 out
[ 4120.112163]          res 40/00:f4:3f:0c:2e/00:00:00:00:00/40 Emask 0x10 (ATA bus error)
[ 4120.112468] ata4.00: status: { DRDY }
[ 4120.112566] ata4.00: failed command: WRITE FPDMA QUEUED
[ 4120.112675] ata4.00: cmd 61/00:d8:3f:00:2e/04:00:00:00:00/40 tag 27 ncq 524288 out
[ 4120.112676]          res 40/00:f4:3f:0c:2e/00:00:00:00:00/40 Emask 0x10 (ATA bus error)
[ 4120.112981] ata4.00: status: { DRDY }
[ 4120.113079] ata4.00: failed command: WRITE FPDMA QUEUED
[ 4120.113188] ata4.00: cmd 61/00:e0:3f:04:2e/04:00:00:00:00/40 tag 28 ncq 524288 out
[ 4120.113189]          res 40/00:f4:3f:0c:2e/00:00:00:00:00/40 Emask 0x10 (ATA bus error)
[ 4120.113493] ata4.00: status: { DRDY }
[ 4120.113596] ata4.00: failed command: WRITE FPDMA QUEUED
[ 4120.113705] ata4.00: cmd 61/00:e8:3f:08:2e/04:00:00:00:00/40 tag 29 ncq 524288 out
[ 4120.113706]          res 40/00:f4:3f:0c:2e/00:00:00:00:00/40 Emask 0x10 (ATA bus error)
[ 4120.114012] ata4.00: status: { DRDY }
[ 4120.114112] ata4.00: failed command: WRITE FPDMA QUEUED
[ 4120.114220] ata4.00: cmd 61/80:f0:3f:0c:2e/02:00:00:00:00/40 tag 30 ncq 327680 out
[ 4120.114221]          res 40/00:f4:3f:0c:2e/00:00:00:00:00/40 Emask 0x10 (ATA bus error)
[ 4120.114527] ata4.00: status: { DRDY }
[ 4120.114628] ata4: hard resetting link
[ 4120.604112] ata4: SATA link up 6.0 Gbps (SStatus 133 SControl 300)
[ 4120.607305] ata4.00: configured for UDMA/133
[ 4120.607328] ata4: EH complete
[ 4120.625081] ata4.00: exception Emask 0x10 SAct 0x3ff0000 SErr 0x400000 action 0x6 frozen
[ 4120.625238] ata4.00: irq_stat 0x08000000, interface fatal error
[ 4120.625347] ata4: SError: { Handshk }
[ 4120.625446] ata4.00: failed command: WRITE FPDMA QUEUED
[ 4120.625553] ata4.00: cmd 61/00:80:3f:cc:2d/04:00:00:00:00/40 tag 16 ncq 524288 out
[ 4120.625554]          res 40/00:cc:3f:b0:2d/00:00:00:00:00/40 Emask 0x10 (ATA bus error)
[ 4120.625858] ata4.00: status: { DRDY }
[ 4120.625956] ata4.00: failed command: WRITE FPDMA QUEUED
[ 4120.626063] ata4.00: cmd 61/00:88:3f:c8:2d/04:00:00:00:00/40 tag 17 ncq 524288 out
[ 4120.626064]          res 40/00:cc:3f:b0:2d/00:00:00:00:00/40 Emask 0x10 (ATA bus error)
[ 4120.635853] ata4.00: status: { DRDY }
[ 4120.635952] ata4.00: failed command: WRITE FPDMA QUEUED
[ 4120.636072] ata4.00: cmd 61/00:90:3f:c4:2d/04:00:00:00:00/40 tag 18 ncq 524288 out
[ 4120.636073]          res 40/00:cc:3f:b0:2d/00:00:00:00:00/40 Emask 0x10 (ATA bus error)
[ 4120.636377] ata4.00: status: { DRDY }
[ 4120.636474] ata4.00: failed command: WRITE FPDMA QUEUED
[ 4120.636580] ata4.00: cmd 61/00:98:3f:c0:2d/04:00:00:00:00/40 tag 19 ncq 524288 out
[ 4120.636581]          res 40/00:cc:3f:b0:2d/00:00:00:00:00/40 Emask 0x10 (ATA bus error)
[ 4120.636883] ata4.00: status: { DRDY }
[ 4120.636981] ata4.00: failed command: WRITE FPDMA QUEUED
[ 4120.637087] ata4.00: cmd 61/00:a0:3f:bc:2d/04:00:00:00:00/40 tag 20 ncq 524288 out
[ 4120.637088]          res 40/00:cc:3f:b0:2d/00:00:00:00:00/40 Emask 0x10 (ATA bus error)
[ 4120.637397] ata4.00: status: { DRDY }
[ 4120.637495] ata4.00: failed command: WRITE FPDMA QUEUED
[ 4120.637601] ata4.00: cmd 61/00:a8:3f:ac:2d/04:00:00:00:00/40 tag 21 ncq 524288 out
[ 4120.637601]          res 40/00:cc:3f:b0:2d/00:00:00:00:00/40 Emask 0x10 (ATA bus error)
[ 4120.637902] ata4.00: status: { DRDY }
[ 4120.638000] ata4.00: failed command: WRITE FPDMA QUEUED
[ 4120.638105] ata4.00: cmd 61/00:b0:3f:a8:2d/04:00:00:00:00/40 tag 22 ncq 524288 out
[ 4120.638106]          res 40/00:cc:3f:b0:2d/00:00:00:00:00/40 Emask 0x10 (ATA bus error)
[ 4120.638407] ata4.00: status: { DRDY }
[ 4120.638504] ata4.00: failed command: WRITE FPDMA QUEUED
[ 4120.638610] ata4.00: cmd 61/00:b8:3f:b8:2d/04:00:00:00:00/40 tag 23 ncq 524288 out
[ 4120.638610]          res 40/00:cc:3f:b0:2d/00:00:00:00:00/40 Emask 0x10 (ATA bus error)
[ 4120.638911] ata4.00: status: { DRDY }
[ 4120.639009] ata4.00: failed command: WRITE FPDMA QUEUED
[ 4120.639114] ata4.00: cmd 61/00:c0:3f:b4:2d/04:00:00:00:00/40 tag 24 ncq 524288 out
[ 4120.639115]          res 40/00:cc:3f:b0:2d/00:00:00:00:00/40 Emask 0x10 (ATA bus error)
[ 4120.639416] ata4.00: status: { DRDY }
[ 4120.639513] ata4.00: failed command: WRITE FPDMA QUEUED
[ 4120.639618] ata4.00: cmd 61/00:c8:3f:b0:2d/04:00:00:00:00/40 tag 25 ncq 524288 out
[ 4120.639619]          res 40/00:cc:3f:b0:2d/00:00:00:00:00/40 Emask 0x10 (ATA bus error)
[ 4120.639920] ata4.00: status: { DRDY }
[ 4120.640035] ata4: hard resetting link
[ 4121.132104] ata4: SATA link up 6.0 Gbps (SStatus 133 SControl 300)
[ 4121.134760] ata4.00: configured for UDMA/133
[ 4121.134773] ata4: EH complete
```

Does this mean that my harddrive is dieing?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Power supply!
These errors are usually related to a bad cable or cable connector, or possibly bad power. The presence of BadCRC or ICRC is a pretty good indicator of a poor quality SATA cable. However, if a better cable does not solve the issue, then it is probably a power problem (loose power cable or backplane connection, poor connectors, poor power splitter, overloaded power supply, too many drives on power rail, bad power supply, etc).

Answer (score 10):

It's most probably not your hard drive, most likely to be your ATA cable or ATA bus. try checking the ATA cable and/or changing it to another cable. also try connecting the hard disk to a different ATA bus on motherboard.

Check this link for more info: https://ata.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/Libata_error_messages